# Combine dicts in a list if they have the same key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

I have a dict that looks like this:

```
{'Item1': [{'Name1': 3}, {'Name2': 4}, {'Name1':7}],
 'Item2': [{'Name7': 44}, {'Name2': 3}, {'Name6':9}, {'Name6':2}]
}
```

I want to combine dictionaries in the list attached to the key such that if there are multiple dicts with the same key, I can combine them (sum) and leave the others as they are.

The output would look like:

```
{'Item1': [{'Name1': 10}, {'Name2': 4}],
 'Item2': [{'Name7': 44}, {'Name2': 3}, {'Name6': 11}]
}
```

I can't figure out how to do this in Python elegantly with a list/dict comprehension.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have a list of dicts? Since you want to collapse multiple copies of a key into a single key, you might as well have a single dict. Abstractly that's what you have anyway, you're just doing in a clumsy manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurred to me just a few minutes after posting the question.

This is what I did:

```
from operator import add
from collections import Counter
results = {}
for item, names in d.items():
        result[item] = (reduce(add, (Counter(name) for name in names)))
```

As the above comments and answers suggest, I am better off using a 1-length dictionary instead of having to combine several later. Still, leaving the answer out here for anyone that needs it.

Answer (score 1):

This uses [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). It is about the most elegant I could come up with, because of the slightly convoluted structure of your input - a list of 1-length dictionaries would indeed be better implemented as a single dictionary, as the comments suggest. This is also what my code transforms it to, although I have provided some more possible tranformations if you really direly need the old data structure. If you do, I would recommend using tuples as your key-value pairs rather than just single-length dicts, as seen in `tuple_output`. I recommend you use `output` or `dict_output`.

```
from collections import Counter

d = {'Item1': [{'Name1': 3}, {'Name2': 4}, {'Name1':7}], 'Item2': [{'Name7': 44}, {'Name2': 3}, {'Name6':9}, {'Name6':2}] }

output = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    c = Counter()
    for sub_dict in v:
        c.update(sub_dict)
    output[k] = c

dict_output = {k: dict(v) for k, v in output.items()}
tuple_output = {k: v.most_common() for k, v in output.items()}
dict_list_output = {k: [{a: b} for a, b in v.most_common()] for k, v in output.items()}

print(output)
#{'Item1': Counter({'Name1': 10, 'Name2': 4}), 'Item2': Counter({'Name7': 44, 'Name6': 11, 'Name2': 3})}

print(dict_output)
#{'Item1': {'Name1': 10, 'Name2': 4}, 'Item2': {'Name7': 44, 'Name2': 3, 'Name6': 11}}

print(tuple_output)
#{'Item1': [('Name1', 10), ('Name2', 4)], 'Item2': [('Name7', 44), ('Name6', 11), ('Name2', 3)]}

print(dict_list_output)
#{'Item1': [{'Name1': 10}, {'Name2': 4}], 'Item2': [{'Name7': 44}, {'Name6': 11}, {'Name2': 3}]}
```

Of course, if you change the starting data structure altogether, it will become a lot easier to manage. If you use a dictionary from strings to Counters, you can use the Counter interface to easily update it (refer to the [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter))

Edit:

Just for fun, done in one line:

```
results = {item: reduce(lambda a, b: [a, a.update(b)][0], names, Counter()) for item, names in d.items()}
```

It was inspired by yours, except this only builds one Counter instance (given as the initial value for reduce) per list. Also, a little bit of a golfy trick is required to reduce properly, as Counter.update is in place. If you're reading this, you probably shouldn't use it, and instead build a data structure with Counters or dicts from the start, as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thank you for showing examples of the different ways to do this. I do agree that tuple_output seems to be the best approach here and I'm restructuring my code to use it.

Comment: Using list comprehension to generate side effects is an awful example of a one-liner. You can also do it without the side effects.

Comment: My bad. It was probably a bad idea to include it. I tried to explain it wasn't intended for serious use, as in this case a one liner will probably impede clarity. You're right though. I'll leave it up for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do want to collapse this into a single `dict` vs `list[dict]` then you can do this without any additional modules with a couple of simple `for` loops:

```
In []:
r = {}
for k, ds in data.items():
    s = {}
    for d in ds:
        for v, c in d.items():
            s[v] = s.get(v, 0) + c
    r[k] = s
r

Out[]:
{'Item1': {'Name1': 10, 'Name2': 4}, 'Item2': {'Name2': 3, 'Name6': 11, 'Name7': 44}}
```

As some seem to be going for one liners:

```
In []:
import itertools as it
from collections import Counter

{k: dict(Counter(v for v, c in it.chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in ds))
                 for _ in range(c)) for k, ds in data.items()}

Out[]:
{'Item1': {'Name1': 10, 'Name2': 4}, 'Item2': {'Name2': 3, 'Name6': 11, 'Name7': 44}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also try with defaultdict

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict
d_new = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    d_dict = defaultdict(int)
    for k1, v1 in chain(*[ i.items() for i in v ]) :
        d_dict[k1]+= v1
    d_new[k] = dict(d_dict)

print (d_new)
```

Output:

```
{'Item1': {'Name1': 10, 'Name2': 4}, 'Item2': {'Name7': 44, 'Name2': 3, 'Name6': 11}}
```

chain(*[ i.items() for i in v ]) will flatten the list of dicts into list of items

Converts

```
[{'Name1': 3}, {'Name2': 4}, {'Name1':7}]
```

to

```
[('Name1', 3), ('Name2', 4), ('Name1', 7)]
```

defaultdict(int) is used to add the values of dict with same keys

Comment: Probably easier to use `itertools.chain.from_iterable(i.items() for i in v)` than construct the list and unpack it into arguments for `chain()`.